# Delete when a Foreign key exist - is there a way to get the id of the key that violated the Foreign key (EF)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys

I am working with entity framework.
I have table A & B in 1:n.
Say I delete many rows in A and one of the a key-row in table A has one or many rows in table B.

I get sqlException with the following text

```
 The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_A_B". 
 The conflict occurred in database "DCDCommunity", table "Template.Template",  
 column 'ApplicationTypeID'.  The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there a way to get the id of the key that violated the Foreign key.

**Important EDIT:**

I know I can check if B has rows.
But that will be prone to persistency problems.
(Lets say that another insert request is issued right after the check.  )

By not checking and letting the database throw an exception I let him deal with the persistency (especially when running on several machines)
Now - If I only had more data in the SQL exception I could rely on this mechanism only.

Comment: If you delete many A, what's to stop their being multiple A's whose deletion violates the foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 1):

`You cannot delete Rows from A (your primary key table) where there are related records in B (foreign table)`. That violates the relationship. Therefore you need to `first delete them from B` and `then delete from A`. Or you can do `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Pls [Check out this example here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/17/sql-server-curious-case-of-disappearing-rows-on-update-cascade-and-on-delete-cascade-t-sql-example-part-2-of-2/)

Comment: You can do both way checking. (1). If `B has NO records` --> `DELETE A.` (2). If `A has a PK record` --> `INSERT INTO B`

Comment: Maybe I did not explain my self well. I am trying to avoid the checking. Checking on an architecture that consists on three databases is prone to problems. i.e. consistency and persistency. I want to let the database handle it. I like the fact that it throws an exception but I would like to know if I can get additional data from it.

Comment: If you implement `ON DELETE CASCADE` database will look after the `DELETE` for you. For `INSERT` you can use a `try{} catch(){}` block and `get the exception type` and act upon that. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I am asking. 
I dont want it to delete. I want it not to delete. and I want it to throw an exception rather then search and solve it with my code. Currently it does all that and I can rely on its mechanism since it is safer than writing it by myself -  because it is guaranteed to work on any db architecture. I just wanted to know if there is a way to get more data from the exception so I can present it. The DB exception is over a specific value . That is what i need in order not to implement it myself.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. `As per OP`, you need to find the `PK id`, right? So PK ID must be in your hand when you try to delete it. Correct? For more details, `Catch the CLR Exception` and check `INNER Exception` where you may get more info if available.

Comment: @kaf  the link you provide in your answer is not working